# how to list mysql databases and it respective engines

Tags: mysql

How do I find out the engines for all databases in a given MySQL instance in a single query? I could query engine for each database individually but would require it in a single go.

Comment: Engines are associated with tables, not databases, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

as Barmar correctly points out, there can be multiple engines in each database

To get all database names-tables-engines you can run:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```